# Is there any forbidden technology in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

Is there any forbidden technology in the Star Wars universe? In other sci-fi works, such as *Dune*, computers and associated technology is banned, but is there anything not allowed in the current canon of *Star Wars*?

Lightsabers were illegal during the rule of the Empire but lightsabers were part of living memory and the destruction of the Jedi happened barely 20 years before ANH. The knowledge of how to make such a weapon wouldn’t be lost to history and therefor making it a bigger challenge to lose the required skills to produce them.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum Lightsabers _is_ the [correct spelling](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11136/58193).

Comment: There is a booming smuggling trade, so I'd say there is plenty of stuff forbidden under the Empire.

Comment: Cloning is illegal in the Old Republic

Comment: In Season 1 of Rebels, the T-7 Ion Disruptor - capable of disabling a starship - was banned because of its gruesome effect on organics. https://www.starwars.com/databank/t-7-ion-disruptor-rifles

Comment: Lightsabers were illegal? How did Vader and his inquisitors continue to use it?

Comment: @Baby Yoda probably by just not caring. Who's going to arrest them?

Comment: I seem to recall various weapons on Star Wars Knights of the Old Republic 1 and 2 that were described as illegal, although of course the player could run all around the republic with them out and wouldn't get stopped.

Comment: Apparently any form of journalism, as the whole galaxy appears devoid of it.

Comment: @Scott - The question was about technology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### According to whom?

If you asked the [Tusken people](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tusken_Raider) of the planet Tatooine, moisture evaporators are a forbidden technology.

> "A moisture farm? Poor locals never stood a chance. The Sand People think all water is sacred and was promised to them."

On System wide scale, [Doctor Evazan's](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cornelius_Evazan) experiments with decraniation is forbidden and warrants a death sentence on 12 different systems.

Galaxy wide, the creation and use of [Planet Killing Superweapons](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Superweapon) is strictly forbidden, since every time anybody makes one they get destroyed shortly after their first discharge.

In the greater universe, Super-sentient AI is strictly taboo according to the Vong. It stands to reason that since machines are not dominant in the far far away Galaxy, the creation of such Artificial Intelligence  is either not possible or restricted.

If you ask the Old Republic, slavery of any kind is illegal, but they lack the will or resources the enforce the law outside of the Core Worlds, so is it really? Ask the Empire and you’ll find that some species are more equal than others. And if you ask the droids, they would answer, if not for their restraining bolts.

Comment: Sapient experimentation and slavery might be forbidden, but they are not really technology. Also, I guess this is a Legends answer, but are the Tuskens forbidden to have moisture evaporators in Legends? And are planet-destroying weapons forbidden, or merely uncommon and expensive?

Comment: The Tuskens worship water, and ANYONE, including moisture farmers are breaking their ban, the penalty is death. I included superweapons as ‘banned’ by the rest of the Galaxy, since they inevitably get destroyed.

Comment: sources for this?

Comment: Maybe "*de facto*" rather than "strictly" (as opposed to *de jure*) :)

Answer (score 9):

A great many technologies would probably be considered illegal/contraband during the rule of the Empire depending on the situation. Jedi Holocrons would be a good example. In the [12th issue](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2015)_12) of the Star Wars comic book, Vader confiscates a large collection of holocrons that were collected by Grakkus the Hutt.

As stated by TheIronCheek in a comment above, the [T-7 Ion Disruptor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/T-7_ion_disruptor_rifle) was banned by the Empire due to the destructive potential that nearly wiped out the Lasat species.

It could be also be possible that [Slicing](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Slicer) tools would be illegal, as they can be used to break through encryption allowing access to restricted areas and data.

Answer (score 1):

## Battle Droids were banned by The Empire

Following the clone wars, The Empire banned construction of all droids capable of wielding weapons. Thus, companies involved in battle droid building, such as [Holowan Laboratories](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Holowan_Laboratories), had to switch to black market to produce assassin droids such as [IG-88](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG-88) series.

Comment: source for this?

Comment: @NKCampbell Tales Of The Bounty Hunters (now Legends)