# Were lightsabers banned in The Galactic Empire?

Tags: star-wars

According to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/223686/931), lightsabers were illegal during the rule of Empire. This looks funny to me because top two brasses of the Empire themselves were the users of the lightsaber.

Were lightsabers really illegal during the rule of Empire? If yes, what's the citation?

Comment: Clearly the Emperor's lightsaber was an exception under the well-known legal precedent *quia ego sic dico*.

Comment: Lord Vetinari, is that you?

Comment: @Cadence Except lots of Empire goons viz. Vader's Inquisitors used to roam around with lightsabers.

Comment: [Very related, potential duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176751/58193)

Answer (score 4):

Just because something is banned doesn't mean those in charge can't allow it for official business. You can't buy a landmine but the army of your country probably has thousands of the things.

The same goes for lightsabers, they're controlled and if you're not Palpatine, Vader, or one of the inquisitors, wielding one is going get stormtroopers shooting at you (and all that entails).

However, there is no actual reference to lightsabers themselves being banned during the reign of the empire (or [during the Republic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177830/was-it-illegal-for-a-non-jedi-to-use-a-lightsaber-in-the-republic?rq=1) for non-jedi), but being a jedi is punishable by death, and there is little evidence that the empire's troops would take the time to work out if the person holding the lightsaber is actually a jedi or not before blasting them (or at least trying).

Comment: I can get license to install landmines on my private property. But, even military can't use bio weapons because it's banned. There's a difference between controlled weapons and banned weapons.

Comment: @BabyYoda - As far as I am aware, your govt is not controlled by a sith.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins It sounds like it is actually, if he can honestly get permission to put landmines on his property,